# Montecarlo integration in D dimension in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, montecarlo

I'm tring to solve a D dimensional integral by Monte Carlo Integration:

[image]

The idea is to generate N point and calculate the aria below te curve as:

[image]

In order to do this i implemented this Python code:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import symbols, integrate     



def f(x,D):                             
  return D*(x**2)



for i in range(1, 9):                    

  x = symbols('x')                      

  print("The exact mathematical value of the integral with D egual", i, "is:", integrate(f(x,i),(x, 0,1)).evalf(2), "\n") 

print("************************************************************************* \n")



N = 10**4

for j in range(1,9):

  ans = 0

  n_tot = N

  n_below_curve = 0


  for i in range(N):

    x0=np.random.uniform(0,1)
    y0=np.random.uniform(0,1)


    if (f(x0,j) <= y0):

      n_below_curve += 1

  ans = ( n_below_curve / n_tot ) * (1*1)



  print("The result of integral with D egual to", j, "is:", ans, ".\n")
```

The output are:

```
The exact mathematical value of the integral with D egual 1 is: 0.33 

The exact mathematical value of the integral with D egual 2 is: 0.67 

The exact mathematical value of the integral with D egual 3 is: 1.0 

The exact mathematical value of the integral with D egual 4 is: 1.3 

The exact mathematical value of the integral with D egual 5 is: 1.7 

The exact mathematical value of the integral with D egual 6 is: 2.0 

The exact mathematical value of the integral with D egual 7 is: 2.3 

The exact mathematical value of the integral with D egual 8 is: 2.7 

************************************************************************* 

The result of integral with D egual to 1 is: 0.6635 .

The result of integral with D egual to 2 is: 0.4681 .

The result of integral with D egual to 3 is: 0.3823 .

The result of integral with D egual to 4 is: 0.3321 .

The result of integral with D egual to 5 is: 0.2978 .

The result of integral with D egual to 6 is: 0.269 .

The result of integral with D egual to 7 is: 0.252 .

The result of integral with D egual to 8 is: 0.2372 .
```

Comparing the exact results of integral with the results of Monte Carlo integration, we can see that the Monte Carlo integration failed.

Where is the error?

Thanks in advance.

- John Snowden

Comment: You're actually computing a 1-dimension integral here. Is it intended?

Comment: Yes but the integral in D dimension is egual to ```D*int_0^1 x^2 dx``` in 1 dimension.

Comment: If you integrate the function D*x^2, then the "box" is 1 * D, not 1 * 1.

Comment: Ok. i changed the condition in: ```if (y0 <= f(x0,j)):``` and i follow your advice. Now the first integral is calculated correctly, the others no....

Comment: You just need to change 2 things: draw `y0` in range [0, j] and replace `1*1` with `1*j` when you compute `ans`.

Comment: Works! But i want to understand. Why it is necessary compute y0 in the range [0,j] ?

Comment: The point (x0, y0) must be drawn in the box. Here the box area is 1 * D, so x0 must be drawn in [0, 1] and y0 must be drawn in [0, D].

Comment: Now i understand, thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why do you need this "below curve" crap?

You're integrating over hypercube, just compute mean value of the function and be done.

E.g., in 3D

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

rng = np.random.default_rng()

D = 3

N = 100000

I = 0.0 # accumulator
for k in range(0, N):
    pt = rng.random(D) # single point sampled
    I += np.sum(pt*pt) # x0^2 + x1^2 + ...

print(I/N) # mean value

def func(x0, x1, x2):
    return x0*x0 + x1*x1 + x2*x2

R = integrate.nquad(func, ((0,1), (0,1), (0,1)), full_output=True)
print(R)
```

will print something like

```
1.0010147193589627
(1.0, 2.5808878251226036e-14, {'neval': 9261})
```

and for 6D case

```
def func(x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5):
    return x0*x0 + x1*x1 + x2*x2 + x3*x3 + x4*x4 + x5*x5

R = integrate.nquad(func, ((0,1), (0,1), (0,1), (0,1), (0,1), (0,1)), full_output=True)
```

I've got

```
1.9997059362936607
(2.0, 5.89710805049393e-14, {'neval': 85766121})
```